# TypeError while working with Numba nopython mode

Tags: python-3.x, jit, numba

I am new to Numba and trying to jit compile code using the nopython mode. But it is returning

`TypeError: compile_kernel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nopython'`.

The colab notebook with all the codes can be found at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MZje-NTmdltZzYmg1b4WDu1Hd5C_nVzR

Where am I getting things wrong? Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not very familir with CUDA development in Numba, but AFAIK you don't need to add `nopython=True` parameter to decorator. `@numba.cuda.jit` should be enough.

Comment: Also it's better to include your code in the post than adding external link, that makes your question easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you're confusing `numba.jit` with `numba.cuda.jit`.    If you look at the documentation for `numba.cuda.jit` [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda-reference/kernel.html?highlight=cuda%20jit#numba.cuda.jit), you'll see that nopython is actually not a parameter.

The difference here is `numba.jit` is the function `jit` within the `numba` package, whereas `numba.cuda.jit` is the `jit` function inside of the `cuda` module of the `numba` package.

Think about it, you can't run python on a GPU, so it's gonna need to be nopython no matter what (and thus doesn't need that parameter).

One thing I do which you might find helpful, is to not use `numba.jit` when trying to compile nopython code (whenever possible).  Instead use `numba.njit`, which always forces nopython mode (and can be used in most situations).